# why does tkinter ttk showing "name ttk is not defined" in python 3.5.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

Consider this simple code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root= Tk()
ttk.Label(root, text='Heading Here').grid(row=1, column=1)
ttk.Separator(root,orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(row=2, columnspan=5)
root.mainloop()
```

when i run this code it's showing error

```
ttk.Label(root, text='Heading Here').grid(row=1, column=1)
NameError: name 'ttk' is not defined
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do `import X`, you are importing a module named `X`. From this point on, `X` will be defined.

When you do `from X import *`, you are *not* importing `X`, you are only importing the things that are *inside* of `X`. `X` itself will be undefined.

Thus, when you do `from tkinter.ttk import *`, you are not importing `ttk`, you are only importing the things *in* ttk. This will import things such as `Label`, `Button`, etc, but *not* `ttk` itself.

The proper way to import `ttk` in python3 is with the following statement:

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

With that, you can reference the ttk label with `ttk.Label`, the ttk button as `ttk.Button`, etc.

**Note**: doing `from tkinter.ttk import *` is dangerous. Unfortunately, `ttk` and `tkinter` both export classes with the same name. If you do both `from tkinter import *` and `from tkinter.ttk import *`, you will be overriding one class with another. The order of the imports will change how your code behaves.

For this reason -- particularly in the case of tkinter and ttk which each have several classes that overlap -- wildcard imports should be avoided. [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official python style guide, officially discourages wildcard imports:

> Wildcard imports ( from  import * ) should be avoided, as they make it unclear which names are present in the namespace, confusing both readers and many automated tools.

---

Note: your question implies you're using python 3, but in case you're using python 2 you can just do `import ttk` rather than `from tkinter import ttk`. `ttk` moved in python 3.

Comment: i agree with your answer but when use the line from tkinter import ttk i am geting same error ' Separator(self,orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(row=0, columnspan=5,sticky="ew")
NameError: name 'Separator' is not defined ',can you suggest me to overcome this error @BryanOakley

Comment: @sujit: use `ttk.Separator`

Comment: I tried that I am getting error 'name ttk is not defined'@Bryan

Comment: @sujit: if you do `from tkinter import ttk`, it is impossible to get `name ttk is not defined`.

Comment: But I am getting error for line 'from tkinter import ttk' not for 'ttk.Separator'

Comment: perhaps you are runnning python 2.7. Your first comment implied that you were able to do "from tkinter import ttk", now you're saying you cannot?   You're making it difficult to help you.

Comment: I am really sorry...`from tkinter import ttk`is working fine in python 3x but when i want to implement `Seperator `Separator(self,orient=HORIZONTAL).grid(row=0, columnspan=3,sticky="ew")` i am getting error as `NameError: name 'Separator' is not defined`

Comment: thanks @Bryan Oakley Its working fine... as `ttk.Seperator`

Answer (score 1):

To import `ttk`, replace the following line:

```
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

with:

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

Otherwise, attributes of `tkinter.ttk` module will be loaded into the current module namespace instead of `ttk` itself.

Answer (score 1):

When you are importing the ttk module, you can do it in 2 ways -

1. `from tkinter import ttk`
   When you do this, ttk is imported almost like a variable, so you can use that `ttk.Label`
2. `from tkinter import *`
   This is called wildcard import. You can't use `ttk.Label` you have to directly write `Label(options)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ttk.Label(root, text='HeadingHere').grid(row=1, column=1) 
NameError: name 'ttk' is not defined
In this remove ttk as follows.    
Label(root, text='HeadingHere').grid(row=1, column=1
```

Now it works fine

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question that was asked, it just provides a workaround.