# there's something wrong with my program and I don't know how to solve it (something about the tkinter module in python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Can someone please help me with that ?
My code is doing me some trouble because of something that's not working(something about the ttk that's related to the task bar and such and more about the main win function ehhh I don't know), and I don't know what to do, I'll be very happy if someone can send me a better version of my code.

Here is my code

```
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from random import choice
import time 

#####################################################################################################################################################
w=Tk()
#w.geometry(500*250)
width_of_window = 500
height_of_window = 250
screen_width = w.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = w.winfo_screenheight()
x_coordinate = (screen_width/2)-(width_of_window/2)
y_coordinate = (screen_height/2)-(height_of_window/2)
w.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" %(width_of_window,height_of_window,x_coordinate,y_coordinate)) # calculating win size and such (sorry apple/linux users ): )
# w.overrideredirect(1)

S=ttk().Style()
S.theme_use('clam')
S.configure('red.Horizontal.Tprogressbar',foreground='red',background='#4f4f4f')
progress=Progressbar(w,style='red.Horizontal.Tprogressbar',orient=HORIZONTAL,length=500,mode='determinate')

def main_win():
    q = Tk()
    q.geometry('427x250')
    l1=Label(w,text="Text", fg='dark grey',bg=None)
    l = ('Calirbi (body)',24,'bold')
    l1.config(font=1)
    l1.place(x=80,y=100)
    q.mainloop()

def bar():
    l4 = label(w,text='loading....',fg='white',bg='#249794')
    lst4=('Calibri (Body)',10)
    l4.configure(font=lst4)
    l4.place(x=0,y=210)
    r=0
    for i in range(100):
        progress['value']=r
        w.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(0.03)
        r+=1
    w.destroy
    main_win()

progress.place(x=-10,y=235)

#Frames
Frame(w,width=427,height=241,bg='#249794').place(x=0,y=0)

b1.button(w,width=10,height=1,text='Get Started',command=bar,border=0,fg='#249794')
b1.place(x=170,y=200)

#labels
l1=Label(w,text="SPLASH",fg='white',bg='#249794')
lst1=('Calirbi (body)',18,'Bold')
l1.configure(font=lst1)
l1.place(x=50,y=80)

l2=Label(w,text="SCREEN",fg='white',bg='#249794')
lst2=('Calirbi (body)',18,'Bold')
l2.configure(font=lst2)
l2.place(x=155,y=82)

l3=Label(w,text="PROGRAMMED",fg='white',bg='#249794')
lst3=('Calirbi (body)',18,'Bold')
l3.configure(font=lst3)
l3.place(x=50,y=110)

w.mainloop()
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 18, in <module>
    S=ttk().Style()
NameError: name 'ttk' is not defined
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why does tkinter ttk showing "name ttk is not defined" in python 3.5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36592982/why-does-tkinter-ttk-showing-name-ttk-is-not-defined-in-python-3-5-1)

Comment: [class tkinter.ttk.Style](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Style)

Answer (score 2):

In your imports, you haven't imported `ttk`:

```
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
```

This import only defines the name `Progressbar` from the `tkinter.ttk` module. You want to import `tkinter.ttk` itself if you want the name `ttk` to be defined.

In the future, it would help others help you better to put a more detailed description of the problem in the title of your post. ;^)

Comment: Btw you haven't actually given the solution :D (`from tkinter import ttk`)

Comment: Ah! Thanks. :^)